# How do I target the second class of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So, I've got these divs:

```js
function classReturn(obj, target) {
  var className = document.querySelector("." + target);
  console.log("." + target);
  animateAdd(className);
}

function animateAdd(thisClass) {
  console.log(thisClass);
  thisClass.classList.add("animate");
  return;
}
```

```html
<div class="block slide-up" onclick="classReturn(this,'slide-up')">
  <p>.slide-up</p>
</div>
<div class="block slide-down" onclick="classReturn(this,'slide- down')">
  <p>.slide-down</p>
</div>
<div class="block slide-left" onclick="classReturn(this,'slide- left')">
  <p>.slide-left</p>
</div>
<div class="block slide-right" onclick="classReturn(this,'slide- right')">
  <p>.slide-right</p>
</div>
```

**My question**: Is there a way I can return the second class of the item that's being clicked, without having to put it in the string?

This would save some time, instead of having to write (this,'className') every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only ever need the second class from classList:

```
function classReturn(obj) {
    console.log(obj.classList[1]); // returns "slide-down"
}
```

Though I should add that combining js with your html is not good practice. It would be better to add an event listener to each `div.block` like this:

```
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('div.block');
blocks.forEach(block => block.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.classList[1]);
}));
```

Comment: Returns Null x.x

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `document.getElementsByClasName('slide-up')[1]` for example. This method will return a list of HTML DOM Elements that has class `slide-up`.

[W3Schools Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function classReturn(obj) {
  // retrieve 2nd class of the div clicked
  var className = obj.classList[1];
  console.log("." + className);
  animateAdd(className);
}

function animateAdd(thisClass) {
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName(thisClass);
  div[0].classList.add("animate");
}
```

```css
.animate {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block slide-up" onclick="classReturn(this,'slide-up')">
  <p>.slide-up</p>
</div>
<div class="block slide-down" onclick="classReturn(this,'slide- down')">
  <p>.slide-down</p>
</div>
<div class="block slide-left" onclick="classReturn(this,'slide- left')">
  <p>.slide-left</p>
</div>
<div class="block slide-right" onclick="classReturn(this,'slide- right')">
  <p>.slide-right</p>
</div>
```

**Hopethis will be helpful!!**
**Thank You**